# Alt currencys blockchain viewer

Tags: blockchain, litecoin

I know we have blockchain.info for bitcoin

I am trying to track a missing FTC transaction going to btc-e (seems a very common thing money going missing with these jokers)

Are there any similar tools for both Litecoin and Feathercoin FTC so I can hold these guiys to account or confirm that my funds where sent etc ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Litecoin Block Explorer: http://explorer.litecoin.net/

Feathercoin Block Explorer: http://ftc.cryptocoinexplorer.com/

You can find all the "lesser" Altcoins on http://cryptocoinexplorer.com

Answer (score 0):

You can find another blocker.io [litecoin block explorer](http://ltc.blockr.io) for alt currency.

[Bockr.io Litecoin block explorer](http://ltc.blockr.io)

Answer (score 0):

There is a pythonproject called moneywagon that tries to be a universal bockchain client library. Take a look through this file, and you can see about 20 different blockchain API's

https://github.com/priestc/moneywagon/blob/master/moneywagon/services.py